# Qt: Clickable 'buttons' on each row custom painted with QAbstractItemDelegate

Tags: qt

I'd like to draw 'clickable' icons (or buttons) on each row of a QListView I'm using my own custom "QAbstractItemDelegate" derived class to paint. Those buttons may change with the custom status of the row (i have access to the underlying data structure during painting).

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** This may not be the *best* way, but here is a way where you have full control. We found it necessary to do this with drawing check boxes.

You can inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate` (or `QAbstractItemDelegate` may work .. have not tried it) and reimplement the `paint` and `editorEvent` methods. You use `QStyle::drawControl()` (after setting the appropriate style options) to draw the control in `paint`, and then manually test for a mouse hit in the `editorEvent` and do something with it. If memory serves me correctly, this code was largely inspired (*cough*, copied, *cough*, *cough*) from looking at the Qt source code for the `QStyledItemDelegate`.

```
void CheckBoxDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                             const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                             const QModelIndex &index) const {
  bool checked = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toBool();

  if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Active) {
      painter->setBrush(QBrush(QPalette().highlight()));
    }
    else {
      painter->setBrush(QBrush(QPalette().color(QPalette::Inactive,
                                                QPalette::Highlight)));
    }
    painter->drawRect(option.rect);
  }

 QStyleOptionButton check_box_style_option;
  check_box_style_option.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
  if (checked) {
    check_box_style_option.state |= QStyle::State_On;
  } else {
    check_box_style_option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
  }
  check_box_style_option.rect = CheckBoxRect(option);

  QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox,
                                     &check_box_style_option,
                                     painter);
}

bool CheckBoxDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event,
                                   QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                   const QModelIndex &index) {
  if ((event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) ||
      (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)) {
    QMouseEvent *mouse_event = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    if (mouse_event->button() != Qt::LeftButton ||
        !CheckBoxRect(option).contains(mouse_event->pos())) {
      return true;
    }
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {
      return true;
    }
  } else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    if (static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key() != Qt::Key_Space &&
        static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key() != Qt::Key_Select) {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  bool checked = model->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toBool();
  return model->setData(index, !checked, Qt::EditRole);
}
```

Comment: One question, how do I detect a mouse move "enter" and "leave" over the area of a given row? (in case I wanted to implement a highlighting of the current row under the mouse cursor)

Comment: I think that is `QEvent::MouseMove`, but I'm not entirely sure. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to put a `qDebug() << event->type()` statement in there, drive you app, and then weed through whatever it spits out to find the events you need to handle.

Comment: QStyleOptionViewItem &option contains hover state

Comment: Also discussed at http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13146-QItemDelegate-enter-event and http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/19587-How-do-I-obtain-mouse-hover-popup-functionality-in-a-Qtableview.